# six times is approx one times? huh?

Tags: approximation, complex-multiplication

So I'm discussing the number of atoms in the universe with a nice chap, but we can't seem to agree. Google told me the answer to be 10^82. He says it's 6x10^82. He says the six isn't relevant with a number so vast.

To my mind the exponent doesn't negate the six. But I am not a mathematician.

- 6x1 is not approximately 1
- 6x10 is not approximately 10
- 6x100 is not approximately 100

So how can six of any number, however enormous, be approximately the same as one times? It would appear to this untrained eye that the exponent makes the approximation worse, not better.

Please will someone explain this to me? Thanks in advance, and please understand - I'm not asking this so I can go back and bedazzled him with superior unearned intellect, nor hate on him either. I'm just a curious person.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "*Approximately equal*" is ambiguous and open to interpretation.  If you wish for a greater deal of specificity, then sure... insist that they include the $6$.  If you do not wish for such a great deal of specificity, then it can be omitted.  The punchline is that $6\times 10^{82}$ is "*within an order of magnitude*" of $10^{82}$.  That is to say, $6\times 10^{82}$ is within the range $(10^{81}, 10^{83})$, and knowing just that much is often more than enough to satisfy most people, especially with numbers so large.

Comment: Suppose I have some number of marbles... maybe it is a small enough number I can fit in my pocket.  Maybe its so many that it could fill the trunk of my car and I couldn't put it in my pocket.  Maybe its so many that I would need a semitruck to carry it all.  Maybe its so much that I would need a big tanker ship to transport them.  Maybe its so many that it would fill a whole country... the whole planet...  In such a conversation, I don't necessarily specify what make or model the car was, or which ship, etc...

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with large numbers like the number of atoms in the universe it's common use as an estimate the number of decimal places needed. That's the exponent when you write the number in scientific notation, so roughly the number of zeroes. It's (approximately) the (base $10$) logarithm of the number.

So you and your friend are both right, using different conventions. Six times as much is indeed larger. But for a number with $82$ zeroes, multiplying by $6$ might add one more zero. So only about an $8\%$ change when you measure that way.

Comment: Douglas Hofstadter, on pp. 124-125 of his 1985 book [**Metamagical Themas**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamagical_Themas), gives a nice description of the necessary use (for current human minds) of progressive fuzziness for approximations when dealing with larger and larger numbers. I give an excerpt in [this 2 April 2008 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/_0SLRzd5t08/m/hPQD3W-p-wUJ). Related to this is a discussion on p. 150 (lower half of left column) of [*Some rapidly growing functions*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF03023057) by Craig Smorynski (1980).